# CSS Scaling of img in React changes position offset behavior

Tags: css, reactjs, image, scale, offset

I am building a component that will display any image inside a parent div and allows dragging of the image (when larger than the div) as well as scaling on both a double click or pinch on mobile.  I am using inline style changes on the image to test the behavior and so far everything works as I wanted...except that when I change the image transform:scale() all the calculations that effectively set the correct limits to prevent offsetting an image outside the parent div no longer behave as expected.  It does work perfectly if I keep the scale=1.

So for example, with a parent Div width and height of 500/500 respectively, and an image that say is 1500x1000, I prevent any "over"offsetting when dragging the image by setting limits of leftLimit = -(1500-500) = -1000 and topLimit = -(1000-500) = -500.  This works perfectly at the initial scale of 1.  However, I have a dblClick event that scales the image upwards at .5 intervals, and once the scale changes from 1 to any other number, the methods I use above to calculate offset Limits are no longer value.  So for example if I increase the scale to 2, in theory that same 1500x1000 image in a 500x500 div should NOW have leftLimit = -(3000-500) = -2500 and topLimit = -(2000-500) = 1500.  But these new calculated limits allow the image to be dragged right out of the parent div region.  For reference here is the code. Any help or methods for testing what's actually going on would be very much appreciated.

Note the image is being loaded as a file for test, it's a fairly large base64 string. The code is as follows (btw, I am figuring my use of so many 'state' variables probably exposes my ignorance of how such values could/should really persist across renderings.  I am still quite new to React) :

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as types from '../../types/rpg-types'
import imgSource from './testwebmap.jpg'
import * as vars from '../../data/mapImage'

const testImg = require('./testwebmap.jpg')

export default function MyMapImage() {
  let divRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  let imgRef = React.useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null)
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
  const [imgTop, setImgTop] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [imgLeft, setImgLeft] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [scHeight, setSCHeight] = React.useState<number>(100)
  const [scWidth, setSCWidth] = React.useState<number>(100)
  const [imgScale, setImgScale] = React.useState<number>(1)
  const [natHeight, setNatHeight] = React.useState<number>(100)
  const [natWidth, setNatWidth] = React.useState<number>(100)
  const [oldXCoord, setOldXCoord] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [oldYCoord, setOldYCoord] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [topLimit, setTopLimit] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [leftLimit, setLeftLimit] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [isScaling, setIsScaling] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
  const [isFirstPress, setIsFirstPress] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
  const [accel, setAccel] = React.useState<number>(1)
  const [touchDist, setTouchDist] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [cfg, setCfg] = React.useState<types.ImageConfig>({
    img: '',
    imgTOP: 0,
    imgLEFT: 0,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    isFirstPress: true,
    isDragging: false,
    isScaling: false,
    divHeight: 500,
    divWidth: 500,
    topLimit: 0,
    leftLimit: 0,
    isLoaded: true,
    oldMouseX: 0,
    oldMouseY: 0,
    touchDist: 0,
  })

  const setNewImageLimits = () => {
    const img = imgRef
    let heightLimit: number
    let widthLimit: number
    console.log(`imgScale is: ${imgScale}`)
    //console.log(`current offsets: ${imgLeft}:${imgTop}`)
    console.log(`img width/Height: ${img.current?.width}:${img.current?.height}`)
    console.log(img)
    img.current
      ? (heightLimit = Math.floor(imgScale * img.current.naturalHeight - cfg.divHeight))
      : (heightLimit = 0)
    img.current
      ? (widthLimit = Math.floor(imgScale * img.current.naturalWidth - cfg.divWidth))
      : (widthLimit = 0)
    setTopLimit(-heightLimit)
    setLeftLimit(-widthLimit)
    setImgLeft(0)
    setImgTop(0)
    console.log(
      'New Image limits set with topLimit:' + heightLimit + ' and leftLimit:' + widthLimit
    )
  }

  const handleImageLoad = () => {
    if (imgRef) {
      const img = imgRef
      //console.log(imgRef)
      let heightLimit: number
      let widthLimit: number
      img.current ? (heightLimit = img.current.naturalHeight - cfg.divHeight) : (heightLimit = 0)
      img.current ? (widthLimit = img.current.naturalWidth - cfg.divWidth) : (widthLimit = 0)
      setTopLimit(-heightLimit)
      setLeftLimit(-widthLimit)
      setNatHeight(img.current ? img.current.naturalHeight : 0)
      setNatWidth(img.current ? img.current.naturalWidth : 0)
      setSCHeight(img.current ? img.current.naturalHeight : 0)
      setSCWidth(img.current ? img.current.naturalWidth : 0)
      console.log('Image Loaded with topLimit:' + heightLimit + ' and leftLimit:' + widthLimit)
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (imgRef.current?.complete) {
      handleImageLoad()
    }
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setNewImageLimits()
    console.log(`imgScale is: ${imgScale}`)
    console.log('Image has with topLimit:' + topLimit + ' and leftLimit:' + leftLimit)
  }, [imgScale])


  function distance(e: any) {
    let zw = e.touches[0].pageX - e.touches[1].pageX
    let zh = e.touches[0].pageY - e.touches[1].pageY
    if (zw * zw + zh * zh != 0) {
      return Math.sqrt(zw * zw + zh * zh)
    } else return 0
  }

  function setCoordinates(e: any) {
    let canMouseX: number
    let canMouseY: number

    if (e?.nativeEvent?.clientX && e?.nativeEvent?.clientY) {
      //console.log(e)
      //canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - cfg.offsetX)
      canMouseX = e.nativeEvent.clientX - cfg.offsetX
      canMouseY = e.nativeEvent.clientY - cfg.offsetY
      //console.log(`${canMouseX}:${canMouseY}`)
    } else if (e?.nativeEvent?.targetTouches) {
      canMouseX = e.nativeEvent.targetTouches.item(0)?.clientX - cfg.offsetX
      canMouseY = e.nativeEvent.targetTouches.item(0)?.clientY - cfg.offsetY
      // This isn't doing anything (noticeable)
      // e.preventDefault();
    } else return {}
    return {
      canMouseX,
      canMouseY,
    }
  }

  const handleMouseUp = (e: any) => {
    let { canMouseX, canMouseY } = setCoordinates(e)
    setIsScaling(false)
    setIsDragging(false)
    setIsFirstPress(true)
    setAccel(1)
    console.log('Mouse UP Event function')
  }
  const handleMouseDown = (e: any) => {
    const { canMouseX, canMouseY } = setCoordinates(e)
    //console.log('Mouse DOWN Event function')
    e.preventDefault()
    //console.log(`Mouse Down ${canMouseX}:${canMouseY}`)
    canMouseX ? setOldXCoord(canMouseX) : setOldXCoord(0)
    canMouseY ? setOldYCoord(canMouseY) : setOldYCoord(0)
    setIsDragging(true)
    setCfg({ ...cfg, isDragging: true })
    if (e?.targetTouches) {
      e.preventDefault()
      if (e?.nativeEvent?.touches?.length > 1) {
        // detected a pinch
        setTouchDist(distance(e))
        setCfg({ ...cfg, touchDist: distance(e), isScaling: true })
        setIsScaling(true)
        setIsDragging(false)
      } else {
        // set the drag flag
        setIsScaling(false)
        setIsDragging(true)
      }
    }
    setIsFirstPress(false)
    setCfg({ ...cfg, isFirstPress: true })
  }

  const handleDoubleClick = (e: any) => {
    const { canMouseX, canMouseY } = setCoordinates(e)
    if (imgScale === 3) {
      setImgScale(1)
    } else {
      setImgScale(imgScale + 0.5)
    }
  }

  const handleMouseMove = (e: any) => {
    let scaling = isScaling
    let dragging = isDragging
    let tempImgScale: number = 1
    const { canMouseX, canMouseY } = setCoordinates(e)

    let yDiff: number
    let xDiff: number
    let newLeft: number
    let newTop: number

    if (e.targetTouches) {
      e.preventDefault()
      if (e.touches.length > 1) {
        //detected a pinch
        setIsScaling(true)
        setIsDragging(false)
        scaling = true
      } else {
        setIsScaling(false)
        setIsDragging(true)
      }
    }
    //console.log(`isScaling : ${isScaling}`)
    if (scaling) {
      //...adding rndScaleTest to force processing of scaling randomly
      let dist = distance(e)
      //Can't divide by zero, so return dist in denom. if touchDist still at initial 0 value
      tempImgScale = dist / (touchDist === 0 ? dist : touchDist)
      //console.log(`imgScale is: ${imgScale}`)
      if (tempImgScale < 1) tempImgScale = 1 //for now no scaling down allowed...
      if (tempImgScale > 2) tempImgScale = 2 //...and scaling up limited to 2.5x
      setSCHeight(Math.floor(imgScale * natHeight))
      setSCWidth(Math.floor(imgScale * natWidth))
      setImgScale(tempImgScale)
      setTouchDist(dist)
    }
    // if the drag flag is set, clear the canvas and draw the image
    if (isDragging) {

      yDiff = canMouseY && oldYCoord ? accel * (canMouseY - oldYCoord) : 0
      xDiff = canMouseX && oldXCoord ? accel * (canMouseX - oldXCoord) : 0
      if (imgLeft + xDiff <= leftLimit) {
        setImgLeft(leftLimit)
      } else if (imgLeft + xDiff >= 0) {
        setImgLeft(0)
      } else setImgLeft(imgLeft + xDiff)
      if (imgTop + yDiff <= topLimit) {
        setImgTop(topLimit)
      } else if (imgTop + yDiff >= 0) {
        setImgTop(0)
      } else setImgTop(imgTop + yDiff)
      if (accel < 4) {
        setAccel(accel + 1)
      }
    }
    //console.log('Mouse **MOVE Event function')
    setOldXCoord(canMouseX || 0)
    setOldYCoord(canMouseY || 0)
  }
  const handleMouseLeave = (e: any) => {
    setIsScaling(false)
    setIsDragging(false)
    setIsFirstPress(true)
    setAccel(1)
    console.log('Mouse LEAVE Event function')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="portrait">
        <div
          ref={divRef}
          className="wrapper"
          onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
          onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
          onTouchEnd={handleMouseUp}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
          onTouchStart={handleMouseDown}
          onTouchMove={handleMouseMove}
          onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
          onDoubleClick={handleDoubleClick}
        >
          <img
            ref={imgRef}
            src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${vars.bigImage}`}
            style={{
              transform: `scale(${imgScale})`,
              transformOrigin: `top left`,
              objectPosition: `${imgLeft}px ${imgTop}px`,
            }}
            onLoad={handleImageLoad}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <span>{`imgLeft: ${imgLeft}px `}</span>
      <span>{`imgTop: ${imgTop}px  `}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem does lie with the use of Scale(), and I could not rely on it for purposes of tracking position and offset.  So I ended up explicitly scaling 'height' and 'width' for the img and keeping the scaling value as a reference when required to calculate new values for these.  The parent Div and Img essentially now look like this:

```
<div
  ref={divRef}
  className="wrapper"
  onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
  onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
  onTouchEnd={handleMouseUp}
  onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
  onTouchStart={handleMouseDown}
  onTouchMove={handleMouseMove}
  onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
  onDoubleClick={handleDoubleClick}
>
  <img
    ref={imgRef}
    src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${vars.bigImage}`}
    style={{
      transform: `translate(${imgLeft}px, ${imgTop}px)`,
      height: `${scHeight}px`,
      width: `${scWidth}px)`,
      transformOrigin: `top left`,
    }}
    onLoad={handleImageLoad}
  />
</div>
```

This works fine, calculated offsets match the expected values, and translation of the image within the parent div behaves as expected.